# How to remove a product from a category magento 1.5

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I'm kind of new in Magento and I'm working on a cron job that removes a product in a specific category after the date that was assigned. With work and the help of Stackoverflow, I came up with this code:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();    
$collection->addfieldtofilter('news_to_date', array(array('to' => $date)));        
foreach($collection as $product) {        
   $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
   $product->save();
 }
```

This checks the actual date and compares it with the date of the products. If the date has passed, the product is disabled. What I need is that instead of disabling the product, the code should remove the product of the category (in this case the category is 'Sales')

I hope you guys can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need get all category ids from product, then remove Sales category ID from category ids array and set them back to product.

Example, Sales category ID is 5.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //Getting all category ids
    $ids = $product->getCategoryIds();
    //Searching array key with value 5 and removing from array
    if (($key = array_search(5, $ids)) !== false) {
        unset($ids[$key]);
        $product->setCategoryIds($ids)
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

P.S. You can use magento cron job functionality, than you do not need to use:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
```

Comment: Your code works. But you missed a semi column in second line inside if condition :)